# mi empresa me solicito trabajar en un proyecto de angular con la version 9.0.7 hay muchos errores de dependencias

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript, chart.js

Intenté instalar las dependencias con npm install y me salieron estos errores

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: softwareqc@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@9.0.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~9.0.6" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@">=12.0.0" from @auth0/angular-jwt@5.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt
npm ERR!   @auth0/angular-jwt@"^5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\edward.arroyave\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-03T14_40_27_204Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\edward.arroyave\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-03T14_40_27_204Z-debug-0.log
```

Para continuar, lo que hice fue forzar la instalación con npm install --force o npm install --legacy-peer-deps, pero ahora tengo un problema bastante grande que no he podido solucionar. Al intentar activar el servidor con ng serve, me dice que hay un error. He intentado borrar tanto el node_modules como el package.json, pero no he podido solucionarlo.
tengo la version de node 18. pero esto usando nvm para utilizar la version 14

```
Your global Angular CLI version (11.0.0) is greater than your local version (9.0.7). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
Warning: Entry point 'ng2-pdf-viewer' contains deep imports into 'D:/Projects/qc/FRONTEND-PROYECTO_QC/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/es5/build/pdf', 'D:/Projects/qc/FRONTEND-PROYECTO_QC/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/es5/web/pdf_viewer'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 681 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 863 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 1.14 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 346 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2023-03-03T14:04:27.679Z - Hash: ebb3fe2581aad672f9fc - Time: 35376ms

ERROR in node_modules/chart.js/types/adapters.d.ts:1:13 - error TS1005: '=' expected.

1 import type { ChartOptions } from './index.esm';
              ~
node_modules/chart.js/types/adapters.d.ts:1:35 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 import type { ChartOptions } from './index.esm';
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

ya instale la version de angular, instale la version que indica de typescript, tambien cambie mi version de node de la 18 a la 14
my packege.json:

```
"name": "softwareqc",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "browser": {
        "fs": false,
        "os": false,
        "path": false
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~9.0.6",
        "@angular/cdk": "~9.2.1",
        "@angular/common": "~9.0.6",
        "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.6",
        "@angular/core": "~9.0.6",
        "@angular/forms": "~9.0.6",
        "@angular/localize": "~9.0.6",
        "@angular/material": "~9.2.1",
        "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.2.4",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.6",
        "@angular/router": "~9.0.6",
        "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.1",
        "@azure/msal-angular": "^1.1.2",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
        "@rxjs/rx": "^4.1.0",
        "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "^6.0.0",
        "apexcharts": "^3.27.3",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
        "chart.js": "^3.7.0",
        "chat.js": "^1.0.2",
        "dayjs": "^1.10.7",
        "dom-to-image": "^2.6.0",
        "echarts": "^5.2.1",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
        "html2canvas": "^1.3.2",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "msal": "^1.4.4",
        "ng-apexcharts": "1.5.12",
        "ng-bootstrap-form-validation": "^5.0.0",
        "ng2-pdf-viewer": "6.4.1",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
        "ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.3",
        "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.0",
        "ngx-print": "^1.2.1",
        "ngx-select-ex": "^6.0.2",
        "ngx-spinner": "^9.0.2",
        "ngx-toastr": "^13.1.0",
        "ngx-toggle-switch": "^2.0.5",
        "pdfmake": "^0.2.6",
        "pdfmake-wrapper": "^2.1.2",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "protractor": "^7.0.0",
        "rxjs": "^6.6.2",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.2",
        "sweetalert2": "^9.17.1",
        "tslib": "^1.10.0",
        "xlsx": "^0.17.5",
        "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.5",
        "@angular/cli": "~9.0.6",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.6",
        "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.6",
        "@types/html2canvas": "^1.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.5.8",
        "@types/jspdf": "^2.0.0",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "@types/pdfmake": "^0.1.20",
        "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.3.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
        "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
        "tslint": "~5.18.0",
        "typescript": "~3.7.5"
    }
```

muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Prueba borrando la carpeta `node_modules` y el `package-lock.json`, luego dale a `npm install` de nuevo. Esas opciones force y legacy-peer-dep son exactamente lo que dicen que hacen y vas a causar este tipo de cosas. De paso, por favor ve a [edit] e indica versión de node y de npm instaladas en tu entorno. Y te sugiero amablemente que no pongas tu pregunta como respuesta en el sitio en inglés, la gente va a tener **menos** ganas de responderte por hacer las cosas mal.

Comment: Te está diciendo que en `softwareqc` y `@auth0/angular-jwt` tienes unas versiones que piden un angular/common que no coincide con el/los que estás definiendo en el package.json. Si no entiendes por qué se usa `~`, o `^`, ve a https://semver.npmjs.com/ y lo verás con tus propios ojos. Ajusta esas dependencias y revalúa si necesitas ~9.0.6 o ^9.0.6 para que no te resulte tan difícil hacer que todo funcione en conjunto

Comment: No sé mucho sobre npm y Angular. Pero, no hay nadie más experimentado en tu empresa a quien le puedas preguntar? No pierdes nada por intentarlo

Comment: @Mateo: Estoy de acuerdo que siempre es bueno compartir dudas y descubrimientos con compañeros de trabajo, pero no olvidemos que todo lo que comunidades como esta nos aporta en el día a día no tiene precio. ¿Cuántas veces visitamos StackOverflow u otros blogs a lo largo del día para seguir aprendiendo o solucionar nuestras dudas/errores? Aprender a "pescar" conocimiento en internet es una de las mayores lecciones que debemos aprender en nuestra profesión.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías usar Node.js 12 porque Angular 9 no es compatible con Node.js 14. [Aquí tienes la lista completa no oficial de compatibilidades](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60258560/5546379). Está genial que uses *nvm* (he escrito un poco sobre él aquí en [Instalar múltiples versiones de Node.js en Windows](https://rafaelneto.dev/blog/instalar-multiples-versiones-nodejs-windows/)).

Por otro lado, debes eliminar la carpeta *node_modules* (yo realmente prefiero renombrarla antes de borrar para poder instalar los nuevos paquetes mientras se borran los paquetes antiguos) y usar el comando *npm install --development* para obtener de nuevo todos los paquetes.

¡Suerte!